# Дерево меню, каталогизация

Tags: алгоритм, php

Доброго времени суток!

Понадобилась необходимость выстроить бесконечное меню со вложениями на сайте. С деревом меню я знаком. Но мне нужно представить все это не в виде

-Главная

- текст
- текст
- текст

-Еще чего

- текст
- текст
- текст

-И ще

```
  - текст
```

А в виде главных элементов на странице.
То есть:
даны категории:

```
            1- Товары                                  2- Услуги
            3- Фирмы                                   3- Рестораны
```

Каждая категория имеет ссылку на подкатегорию, в подкатегории еще категории и т.д
Вопрос возник в том, как организовать это?
Что-бы не отображать сразу все дерево, а циклически переходить вглубь при выборе конкретной категории.
Может существуют готовые библиотеки или алгоритмы работы, буду рад.
Может коряво описал, но смысл думаю донес=) Извеняюсь если что не так=)
Заранее спасибо.

Comment: структура БД уже реализована?

Comment: Не могу понять в чем сложность. Две самые распространенные схемы это: или каждая категория/подкатегория в БД содержит id родительской категории, или id родительской и дочерней. При выборе одной и категорий, мы получаем ледующее звено в данной цепочке и так далее.

Comment: @Gedweb, нет, структура БД не реализована. поэтому и спрашиваю совета

Answer (score 2):

Мне кажется проще сделать таблицу `category`, в ней поля `id | title | url | id_main`

`id_main` - это категория родителя, если 0 значит это главная. А дальше дело циклов.

Comment: Более менее нарисовал картину в голове) пойду реализую в коде)